# cgi-bin python script not working because of too many file permissions?

Tags: python, web-hosting, file-permissions

Yesterday python got activated on my web space as cgi-bin. I tried to run some scripts, but with little success. I asked the support for help, they kept saying the file permissions where the issue and I should set set them to 755. They already where 777. It took me a while to figure it all out, file extension, other apache/htaccess options, but the file permission really where an issue. Although they where at 777 it only works with 755.

How can it be that a script with 777 is not working but works fine with 755, with less permissions? Could somebody explain to me how that's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain scripts refuse to run if permissions are too liberal, to avoid potential security issues